# Conversion of DATE in SQL400

Tags: sql

I have a date in YY/MM/DD format. Is there any way to convert this date in DD/MM/YY format through an SQL query in SQL-400.

Comment: What exactly is "SQL-400"? I have never heard of that DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

In `Sql Server` you can do the below

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(20)='15/02/25'

SELECT RIGHT(@DATE,2)+'/'+  LEFT(RIGHT(@DATE,5),2)+'/'+ LEFT(@DATE,2)
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06245/1) to view result